# VeeValidate (Vue 3.0) - validation with useField

Tags: vuejs3, vee-validate

I have a vue 3.0 component which structure looks like this (Sorry I can't post the production code):

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="value" name="test"/>
    <selectList/>
  </div>
</template>
```

The component has a modelValue prop, which is an Object `{value: '', text: ''}`. I'm trying to use useField to validate the value of the input field. I need to call the validate function many times inside of the script.

```
const { errors, value, validate, resetField } = useField('test', rules)
```

The problem here is that the value is always an object like the modelValue of the component `{value: '', text: ''}` and not the value of the input field.

My question is: How can I tell veeValidate to validate the value of the input field and not the modelValue of the component.

Thank you in advance